# Performance of database during table loads

Tags: java, oracle, performance

I am using `Oracle 12c` database. Currently there are two different jobs are running from java which inserts data into two different tables for example `A and B` from same database at the same time.

The amount of data loads are quiet large and i am currently facing performance issue on table `A` where one of my java job are taking more than 18 hours to load data into tables.

I would like to know is this the performance issue happens on this java job for table `A` because i am using the same database where the other java job is also running and inserting data on table `B` ?

Comment: 18 hours looks very long. Please detail size (in MB/GB - not only number of rows) of loaded data. If possible post SQL code that is used by the jobs.  Without detailed database activity information (like Statspack or AWR reports - or SQL trace file) we can only try to guess.

Comment: Are you inserting "everything" in one transaction? Or do you have autocommit on, so you perform one commit per line? Batch-sizes might help - but without code and more info this is just guessing.

Comment: It really depends on the method you use to load these data: ["slow-by-slow"](https://asktom.oracle.com/Misc/slow-by-slow.html) or using a batch (external table, sqlloader...)

Comment: In general, a native bulk loading solution as suggested by @loic is always a better choice in terms of performance than using Java. Personally I have seen performance improve by multiple orders of magnitude when using external tables instead of Java (90 minutes in Java vs. under 10 seconds to do "insert as select"  with external tables).

Answer (score 0):

In case tables A and B are loaded using best practices (external tables, sqlldr), ensure your redo logs are properly configured (size, number of groups).

In case table A and B are loaded row by row with intermediate commits, then go for best practices instead.